# Django 2.1.5 Authentication (login/logout) breaks on Browser Back-button

Tags: django

I created a simple login logout app using the Out of the box django LoginView and LogoutView. In my app, I can signup using CreateView, list the users using ListView and get user details using DetailView.

I am seeing issues with login and logout when I click the browser's back button.
Issues:

1. Upon login, I am redirected to index page. However when I click the back button, I land back at login page and can login with other valid user.
2. Upon logout, I am redirected to index page. However when I click the back button, I can view the logged-in data such as the list page and details page.

The code for my app (accounts) is :

```
settings.py
<code>
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/accounts/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/accounts/"


project urls.py
<code>
urlpatterns = [
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
]


app urls.py
<code>

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
 app_name = 'accounts_app'
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.IndexPage_cview.as_view(), name="index_curl"),
path("login/", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
path("signup/", views.SignUp_cview.as_view(), name="signup_curl"),
path("super/", views.adminlist_cview.as_view(), name="super_curl"),
path("superdetail/<int:pk>", views.admindetail_cview.as_view(), 
name="super_detail_curl"),
]


app views.py
<code>
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,CreateView, ListView, 
                                  DetailView
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from . import forms

class IndexPage_cview(TemplateView):
   template_name = "accounts/index.html"


class SignUp_cview(CreateView):
  form_class = forms.UserCreate_cform
  success_url = reverse_lazy("login")   #redirect to /accounts/login/
  template_name = "accounts/signup.html"

class adminlist_cview(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
  template_name = 'accounts/super_list.html'
  model= auth.models.User

  def get_queryset(self):
     return auth.models.User.objects.order_by('username')


class admindetail_cview(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
   template_name = 'accounts/super_detail.html'
   model= auth.models.User

  def get_object(self):
      return get_object_or_404(auth.models.User, pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))




app model.py
<code>
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models


class User_cmodel(auth.models.User):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)


app form.py
<code>
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserCreate_cform(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
        model = get_user_model()


base.html
```

```html
<div class="container">

<a href="{% url 'accounts_app:index_curl' %}">Home</a>

    <ul >
     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}" >Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'accounts_app:super_curl' %}>Db List</a></li>
            {% endif %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'accounts_app:logout' %}>Log out</a></li>
       {% else %}
           <li><a href="{% url 'accounts_app:login'%}" >Log in</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'accounts_app:signup_curl' %}">Sign up</a></li>
       {% endif %}

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container mycontent">
          {% block content %}

          {% endblock %}

     </div>
```

```
login.html
```

```html
 {% extends "base.html" %}

 {% block content %}
 <div class="container">

  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form method="POST" >
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% form %}
   <input type="submit" value="Login" >
  </form>
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

No where in the code, you are making the views available only for logged in user. All your views are accessible by anybody.

If you are using custom Auth backend you can use @login_required decorator from django.contrib.auth.decorators. To ensure the user is logged in before going to the view.

You should read this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users